# mvc-System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Hey...
How can I send submit buttons'id from ViewUserControl to controler on post action? When I had normal view I could write something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public  ActionResult KontaktIzabran(string myId)
{
    //some code 

}
```

Now myId is alwasy null....
Here is my UserControl

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<KontaktModel>" %>
<%@ OutputCache Duration="1200" VaryByParam="*" %>
<div id="sign-in-pop" class="popup">    
<div class="modal fat-form">
    <div class="clipper">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="content">Sign In</div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>                    
    <% Html.BeginForm("IzborKontaktaPopUp", "Kontakt"); %>
         <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Naziv)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Naziv) %>  
            <input type="submit" value="Traži" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" />
            <input type="submit" value="Dodaj novi" name="noviKontakt" />
        </div>
    <% Html.EndForm(); %>
</div>       
</div>
```

Comment: can you show your view/user control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public  ActionResult KontaktIzabran(string myId, string noviKontakt)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(noviKontakt))
    {
        // <input type="submit" value="Dodaj novi" name="noviKontakt" />
        // was used to submit the form
    }
    else
    {
        // <input type="submit" value="Traži" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" />
        // was used to submit the form
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but both strings are null no metter which button was clicked. This works when I have just View but when I use UserContol passed values are always null :(

Comment: @Cipiripi, that's weird. The name of the submit button which is clicked should be send to the server. Could you look with `FireBug` what parameters are exactly sent in the request? Also you are not nesting forms, are you? And finally I see that you have an `OutputCache` directive in your user control. Try removing it to make sure that it is not interfering in some way.

Comment: This form act like pop up and it is a kind of nested form. I tried to remove OutputCache but everything is still same

Comment: @Cipiripi, do you have nested `<form>` tags in your HTML after showing this user control? If yes, then this is your problem. This is not allowed.

Comment: @Cipiripi, [the specification](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html) forbids you nesting HTML forms or you will get undefined behavior. You might need to remove the outer form or reorganize your markup differently so that you never have nested forms.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you don't have a form field called "myId", so the submit can't send that back to the controller.  Instead it will send back a FormCollection containing the current values of these:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Naziv)%>
<input type="submit" value="Traži" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" />
<input type="submit" value="Dodaj novi" name="noviKontakt" />
```